# How to make custom Drush commands to work on remote instance

Tags: drush

I have developed custom Drush commands that includes some shell commands all which work locally. I would like them to work also on the remote instance with aliases that have the remote settings. Here is how the shell commands are currently executed:
//executes command

```
function execute_command($command)
{
    drush_log(dt('COMMAND: @command', array('@command' => $command)), 'notice');
    //any shell command fore example 'cp some/source dest/dir','tar xvf some.tgz',etc
    drush_shell_exec($command);
    drush_log(drush_shell_exec_output(), 'debug');
}
```

So, I would like to wrap this into some Drush API so they also execute on remote instance. Is it possible? How should I make the shell commands part of my custom Drush commands to run on the remote instance when user does something like:

```
drush @remote-alias custom-command
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the remote site also has to have the commands as well in order to execute successfully.

Comment: Oh my god! its working....ups one issue: <b>sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified</b> Any idea?

Comment: Did you have to add the commands to the remote site?

Comment: yes. The Drush custom commands have to be installed on the remote instance to work

Comment: As I thought. Also, consider version controlling commands so if you change them you can issue a git pull on the remote server to keep everything in sync.

Comment: You should be able to get around your sudo problem by creating a sudoers file - tho that is off-topic for this board.